# Eclipse error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap spac

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-adt

While trying to run my relatively small app, I am constantly getting the out of heap space memory error.  I'm running eclipse on Gentoo with 8GB of ram.

Here is my eclipse.ini changes:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-Xms512m
-Xmx8192m
```

And my Ant external tools custom JRE parameters:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx8192m
```

What else can I do? I am constantly receiving in the eclipse log:

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2013-11-28 18:54:55.503
!MESSAGE Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.BitSet.initWords(BitSet.java:164)
    at java.util.BitSet.<init>(BitSet.java:159)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.bitSetFromLabelList(SsaMethod.java:137)
    ...
```

Comment: Sometimes happens to me if I have too many projects open simultaneously. Can you close some projects?

Comment: Your MaxPermSize is very large. why do you need 2G for it?

Comment: I have three projects open, so I will try closing some.  And perm size I tried increasing just to see if it would help. [EDIT] Closed it down to 2, which i edit regularly.  I should also state this problem now occurs on both projects, both of which ran fine in the past.  I can't think of any recent event that this problem occurred after, it seems random to me.

Comment: I am also getting a "Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
GC overhead limit exceeded" error randomly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure as to why, but I've solved it by removing the Google API libraries that were included.  I also removed the android-support-v4 library and now my apps compile fine.  In my build path I now only have the android libs.

Answer (score 0):

Is 8 GB your max available RAM? 
If that's the case, did you try to reduce Xmx? As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358328/why-does-the-sun-jvm-have-a-fixed-upper-limit-for-memory-usage-xmx), there is a reason for that boundary. Setting it to your max RAM would not be the intention behind it and may cause system degradation and other weired things. Try setting Xmx to something like 2048. If you get OOMs, slowly go up with that boundary. Even with huge models I never had to assign 8GB, yet.

If that doesn't help, could you add the code of the place that causes the OOM?

Comment: I have set Xmx to 1G, 2G, 4G, and 8G, as well as trying 1024 / 2048 / 4096 / 8192m out of frustration.

I will say these errors happen:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space,
Unhandled event loop exception,
Unable to execute dex: Java heap space