# What happens if I allocate max -Xmx2048m memory to Java Process of 64 bit Linux machine having 2GB RAM?

Tags: java, linux, memory-management, jvm, out-of-memory

I have my Java Spring Application running in 64 bit Linux machine having 2GB RAM. What happens if I allocate max -Xmx2048m memory to Java Process. Because 64 bit machines are allowing me give that configuration, if too much of RAM used by JAVA will it causes any crash?

Comment: The answers to the linked to question are I think sufficient for this question. Please explain why not if this doesn't suffice. You may be interested [in this read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3358383/589259) as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, your computer will just use virtual memory, if your 2GB of physical RAM are in use.

Comment: OK, true if the system has a swap defined, but even then: you could run out of swap too. Question is now marked as dupe...